# can't test app on my mobile : Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Tags: android, testing

I am new to Android Studio and made an app but its not running on my physical device HTC one M8 giving and error like Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

htc one m8 
android version: 5.0.2

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.darab.crazy_tip_calc"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `minSdkVersion 15` instead of **22**

**android:minSdkVersion**

An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.darab.crazy_tip_calc"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your device OS version is lower than you're app SDK version.

```
minSdkVersion 22
targetSdkVersion 22
```

Check your device version. I would suggest to set minSdkVersion to 15 or the the API level of your device. And this is 21 (5.0.2 of your M8).

Answer (score 0):

Check your minSdk version and Target Sdk Version.

Comment: Target SDK doesn't matter for this issue.